# Deserialization using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I'm new to C# and i want to deserialize the JSON file into the API using NewtonSoft but it lead me to this error
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'API.JSonConfiguration.exampleLibrary' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

"To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Path '', line 1, position 1.'"

```
        string url = @"http://180.232.67.229/api/jfiller";
        string Data = new WebClient().DownloadString(url
        exampleLibrary json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<exampleLibrary>(Data);
        MessageBox.Show(json.filler_id);
```

exampleLibrary Class:

```
    public string filler_id { get; set; }
    public string filler_title { get; set; }
    public string filler_type { get; set; }
```

**JSON**

```
[
 {
    "filler_id":"1",
    "filler_title":"Star118 E-CarDemo",
    "filler_type":"1",
    "filler_file":"Star118CarTeaser‌​1.mp4",
    "filler_durat‌​ion":"83",
    "created_a‌​t":"2017-06-10 09:08:41",
    "updated":"2017-06-10 09:08:41","status":"0"
  },
  {
    "filler_id":"2",
    "filler_title":"Sta‌​r118",
    "filler_type":‌​"2",
    "filler_file":"S‌​tar118Solar1.PNG",
    "f‌​iller_duration":"10"‌​,
    "created_at":"2017-‌​06-10 09:09:26",
    "updated":"2017-06-10 09:09:26","status":"0"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you post your JSON string?

Comment: [{"filler_id":"1","filler_title":"Star118 E-CarDemo","filler_type":"1","filler_file":"Star118CarTeaser1.mp4","filler_duration":"83","created_at":"2017-06-10 09:08:41","updated":"2017-06-10 09:08:41","status":"0"},{"filler_id":"2","filler_title":"Star118","filler_type":"2","filler_file":"Star118Solar1.PNG","filler_duration":"10","created_at":"2017-06-10 09:09:26","updated":"2017-06-10 09:09:26","status":"0"}]

Comment: you can try to remove the "[" & "]" from your json string, and put your json here : json2csharp.com, and parse your json using that specific class

Comment: Added formated JSON string to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<exampleLibrary>>(Data);
```

You have an array of data but don't specify it in your JsonConvert or in your exampleLibrary Class(That I can see from your posted code).

Comment: I get an error of :

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[API.JSonConfiguration.exampleLibrary]' to type 'API.JSonConfiguration.exampleLibrary'.'
when I use             exampleLibrary json = (exampleLibrary)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<exampleLibrary>>(Data);
because it looks for cast

Comment: List<exampleLibrary> json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ex‌​ampleLibrary>>(Data)‌​.ToList(); The object you will get returned will be a list of ex‌​ampleLibrary.